# Pinterest pinit button not working on my website the image does not show it appears broken

Tags: pinterest

```
[ProductTitle]
[ThumbnailImage]
  <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=lerivinos.com&media=lerivinos.com" 
     class="pin-it-button" 
     count-layout="horizontal">
  Pin It
  </a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
[OurPrice]
[AddToCart]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So... do you have a question or something? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq (or other questions) in order to phrase a question that can also be answered with the given information.

Answer (score 2):

your sample code doesn't have the img link which pinterest give you in the code snippet.

Assuming you mis-copied and omitted it, I had the same problem because pinterest give you this:

```
<img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
```

I had to add http: to the src to get it to work, ie:

```
<img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The media parameter of your pintrest url should point at your image file, like so:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=lerivinos.com&media=https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" 
     class="pin-it-button" 
     count-layout="horizontal">
  Pin It
  </a>
```

From the [pintrest goodies page](http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/)